# Android ROOM, insert won't return ID with first insert, but will return with 2nd insert onwards

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-room, sql-insert

School project and I'm pretty new to Android development.

**The problem**

I have a button with a onClick listener in a **save person fragment** which will save person data to the database. Everything works fine except for some reason **with the first click** it wont return me the **inserted row ID** but it will do so with 2nd click onwards.

I really need this ID in before proceeding to the next fragment.

Not sure if this is important but whenever I return (reload) to this **save person fragment**, the behaviour is always the same that the first click allways fails to capture the inserted row ID.

input data:

```
first name = John
last name = Smith
```

Just for demo purpose, if I will try to use this button 3x to insert the person data (returned insert ID is in the log), I will get all 3 rows in database with name John Smith, but the very first inserted row ID is not captured (default initialised value is **0**), please see the log below:

**Log**

```
2020-10-19 12:49:20.320 25927-25927/ee.taltech.mobile.contacts D/TEST_ADD_PERSON_ID: insertedPersonId: 0
2020-10-19 12:49:40.153 25927-25927/ee.taltech.mobile.contacts D/TEST_ADD_PERSON_ID: insertedPersonId: 5
2020-10-19 12:49:40.928 25927-25927/ee.taltech.mobile.contacts D/TEST_ADD_PERSON_ID: insertedPersonId: 6
```

**EDITED ORIGINAL post**

As suggested in the comments, I'm trying to go about the way of using LiveData and observer, but I'm still little bit stuck.

**The setup**

The below is the current setup.

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
data class Person(

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addPerson(person: Person): Long
```

**Repository**

```
class PersonRepository(private val personDao: PersonDao) {

    val readAllPersonData: LiveData<List<Person>> = personDao.readAllPersonData()

    suspend fun addPerson(person: Person): Long {
        return personDao.addPerson(person)
    }
```

**ViewModel**

I'm not sure if I'm doing things right at all here. I broke it down here in steps and created separate variables `insertedPersonILiveData` and `insertedPersonId`.
How could pass the returned row id to `insertedPersonILiveData`?

```
class PersonViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
        var insertedPersonILiveData: LiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData<Long>()
        var insertedPersonId: Long = 0L
    
        val readAllPersonData: LiveData<List<Person>>
        private val repository: PersonRepository
    
        init {
            val personDao = ContactDatabase.getDatabase(application).personDao()
            repository = PersonRepository(personDao)
            readAllPersonData = repository.readAllPersonData
        }
    
        suspend fun addPerson(person: Person) = viewModelScope.launch {
            insertedPersonId = repository.addPerson(person)
        // ****************************************************************       
        // insertedPersonILiveData = insertedPersonId (what to do here) ???
        // ****************************************************************       
        }
```

**Save person fragment**
This is the way I'm calling out the addPerson via modelView.

```
val person = Person(0, firstName, lastName)

lifecycleScope.launch {
    personViewModel.addPerson(person)
}
Log.d("TEST_ADD_PERSON_ID","insertedPersonId: ${personViewModel.insertedPersonId}")
```

And this is the way I have done the observer (not sure if it's even correct).

```
val returnedIdListener: LiveData<Long> = personViewModel.insertedPersonILiveData
returnedIdListener.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Long> { id: Long ->
    goToAddContactFragment(id)
})


private fun goToAddContactFragment(id: Long) {
    Log.d("TEST_ADD_PERSON_ID", "id: " + id)
}
```

**Create database**

```
@Database(
    entities = [Person::class, Contact::class, ContactType::class],
    views = [ContactDetails::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class ContactDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun personDao(): PersonDao
    abstract fun contactTypeDao(): ContactTypeDao
    abstract fun contactDao(): ContactDao
    abstract fun contactDetailsDao(): ContactDetailsDao

    companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile
        private var instance: ContactDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): ContactDatabase {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): ContactDatabase {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, ContactDatabase::class.java, "contacts_database")
                .addCallback(
                    object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                            val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<SeedDatabaseWorker>().build()
                            WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(request)
                        }
                    }
                )
                .build()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems that you have multiple ViewModels for the same Fragment, why is that the case? if you had both person and contact repositories in the same ViewModel you wouldn't need to pass the id via Fragment

Comment: @Stachu good catch, I was just playing around with something before and forgot it there. I have removed this from the code. Updated the post accordingly as well. For the record, I'm only using 1 model view per fragment.
Either way, the problem remains. It won't capture the id on the first click. Any ideas?

Comment: my guess is that Log runs before `insertedPersonId` is updated, so even though it actually has ran twice you only see the value from before the update. You could set the `insertedPersonId` as LiveData<Long> and use the observer to trigger on the change. Another option is to make `addPerson` in viewmodel a suspend function and then call it from  e.g. `addPersonAndProcessId`. What would fit you better?

Comment: @Stachu I would really like to learn and understand how to go about the observer method (gotta learn it). Right now I'm struggling to understand how to set up `insertedPersonId` in `PersonViewModel` class. I mean what goes here   `var insertedPersonId: LiveData<Long> = ...` ? How to initially valuate it?

Comment: Would it be something like this?
`var insertedPersonId: LiveData<Long> = MutableLiveData<Long>()`

Comment: I updated the post ( **ViewModel** and **Save person fragment** )  to try to get the row id result via LiveData and observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a coroutine to run `addPerson`, and then immediately calling `Log` with the current value of `insertedPersonId` in the viewmodel. The coroutine will run, insert the person, and update the VM with the ID of the inserted row, but that will happen long after your `Log` has run. Probably all of your results are actually the ID of the last record that was inserted.

I'm new to a lot of this too, but just based on what you have now, I think you just need to add

```
insertedPersonILiveData.value = insertedPersonId
```

in your `addPerson` function. That way you're updating that `LiveData` with a new value, which will be pushed to any valid observers. You've written some code that's observing that `LiveData` instance, so it should get the update when you set it.

---

**edit** your problem is that `insertedPersonILiveData` is the immutable `LiveData` type, so you can't set the value on it - it's read-only. You're *creating* a `MutableLiveData` object but you're exposing it as a `LiveData` type.

The recommended pattern for this is to create the **mutable** one as an internal object, expose a reference to it as an **immutable** type, and create a setter method that changes the value through the mutable reference (which it can access internally)

```
class myViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // mutable version is private, all updates go through the setter function
    // (the _ prefix is a convention for "private versions" of data fields)
    private val _lastInsertedPersonId = MutableLiveData<Long>()
  
    // we're making the instance accessible (for observing etc), but as
    // the immutable LiveData supertype that doesn't allow setting values
    val lastInsertedPersonId: LiveData<Long> = _lastInsertedPersonId

    // setting the value on the MutableLiveData instance
    // is done through this public function
    fun setLastInsertedPersonId(id: Long) {
        _lastInsertedPersonId.value = id
    }
}
```

and then your observer would just call `lastInsertedPersonId.observe`, you don't need to copy the `LiveData` and observe that (like you're doing with `returnedIdListener`.

That's the basic pattern right there - internal `MutableLiveData`, exposed publicly as an immutable `LiveData` `val`, with a setter method to update the value. Everything outside the view model either observes the `LiveData` that's visible, or calls the setter method to update. Hope that makes sense! It's not that complicated once you get your head around what's basically going on

Comment: Unfortunately  `insertedPersonILiveData.value = insertedPersonId` is not allowed because as per the message: `Cannot assign to 'value': the setter is protected/*protected and package*/ for synthetic extension in '<library Gradle: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.2.0@aar>'`
Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh it's because you've made the field an immutable ``LiveData`` type (even if you're assigning a ``MutableLiveData`` instance to it) so there's no setter on that type. I posted an edit explaining how all that works

Comment: Hey man. Thank you so much. I'm super grateful for your time helping me. I cannot thank you enough. I'm sure someone else will find this helpful as well. Cheers